# How to replace ALL particular string appear in DataFrame into another string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, replace

I know this theme has been discussed hundreds of times and, of course, I tried everything seemed fine such as

```
df.replace("x", "y", regex=True)
df.str.replace
```

methods also but somehow it did not work for my DataFrame.

I have  a DataFrame like below

```
To          From             CC               Title          Body
aa@bb   cc@rr; cd@ee    bg@hy; rg@we         jkasdf         jklasdf
er@ty    po@we          oi@we; we@iw         kljasldf        kasdf
```

I have some weird mail address such as /o-exchange\Smith--- because I retrieved outlook email data from my organization's Exchange email server. Thing is that it seems like some people has a few types of this weird address so I want to alter them into one unique email for that particular person.

So I tried like

```
df = df.replace("weird email", "unique email", regex=True)
and 
df['From'] = df['From'].str.replace("weird address", "unique address", regex=True)
```

but it did not replace all the weird address into the same unique address after all. 
Is there any pythonic way to replace ALL particular string into another string?

Sample of inputs and outputs for my DataFrame is such as below

Input

```
        To                          From                            CC                
      abc@we                      weird@ww              long@ww; exchange@ee  
 weird@ww; exadress@ww             long@ww              long@ww; exchange@ww
```

I checked all variety of weird address that the particular person has and I coded like

```
df = df.replace('PersonA weird address1', 'Unique addressA')
df = df.replace('PersonA weird address2', 'Unique addressA')

df = df.replace('PersonB weird address1', 'Unique addressB')
df = df.replace('PersonB weird address2', 'Unique addressB')
```

and my wanted outputs are like

```
        To                          From                            CC                
      abc@we                      Unique@C              Unique@A; Unique@B  
 Unique@C; exadress@ww             Unique@A              Unique@A; Unique@B
```

I made a list of the weird address and the particular person who has the address.
So I just wanna integrate all into one unique address like above.

Comment: can you post sample input and output

Comment: Add your expected output for the given sample data.

Answer (score 0):

create a dictionary with keys as what you have and values as what you want
than use map on each column

```
keys = ["".join(x) for x in it.permutations(["a","b","c","d"],3)]
values = ["".join(x) for x in it.permutations(["e","f","g","h"],3)]
rand_dict = {}
for k in keys:
    rand_dict[k]=random.choice(values)
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["a"] = random.choices(keys,k = 10)
df["b"] = random.choices(keys,k = 10)
df["c"] = random.choices(keys,k = 10)
#till here we created a demo DataFrame

for col in df:
    df[col] = df[col].map(rand_dict).fillna(df[col])
```